# Usage of tf.keras within R

Tags: r, tf.keras

I want to convert my articial neural network implementations to the new tensorflow 2 platform, where keras is an implicit part of (tf.keras). Are there any recommended sources that explain the implementation of ANNs using tensorflow 2/tf.keras within R?

Furthermore, why there is an extra [keras package](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/releases) from F. Chollet available, when keras is as mentioned an implicit part of tensorflow now?

Sorry guys maybe for such basic questions, but my own searches were unfortunately not crowned with success.

Comment: I found this book, by Chollet and Allaire (CEO of RStudio) to be a great resource on using Keras in R: https://www.manning.com/books/deep-learning-with-r

Comment: Thanks! This book is well-known and covers tensorflow/keras with R, but not tensorflow/keras 2.

Answer (score 0):

From original tensorflow documentation I extract the following Python code:

```
input1 = keras.layers.Input(shape=(16,))
x1 = keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu')(input1)
input2 = keras.layers.Input(shape=(32,))
x2 = keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu')(input2)
added = keras.layers.add([x1, x2])

out = keras.layers.Dense(4)(added)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[input1, input2], outputs=out)
```

My own R conversions are

```
library(tensorflow)
k <- tf$keras
l <- k$layers

input1 <- k$layers$Input(shape = c(16,?))
x1 <- k$layers$Dense(units = 8, activation = "relu") (input1)
input2 <- k$layers$Input(shape = c(32,?))
x2 <- k$layers$Dense(units = 8, activation = "relu") (input2)
added <- k$layers$add(inputs = c(x1,x2))
```

My question hopefully seems not to be too stupid, but I've problems to implement a python tuple resp. scalar into its R equivalent. So my question: How must the shape argument in the input layers be converted into R?

Answer (score 0):

I think the following page should provide the answer to your question: https://blogs.rstudio.com/ai/posts/2019-10-08-tf2-whatchanges/.

In essence, your code should stay the same if you are using Keras with a version 2.2.4.1 or above. For more details, refer to the linked site above.